# How to use a 360 image as a skybox in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, skybox, 360-panorama

I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3 with SceneKit

I am making a game that takes place on a floating island in the sky. I want the background to be a nice sky with clouds, and I want it to move around accordingly when the camera moves like a skybox would.

I can use an array of 6 images that wrap around to make a skybox, but I can't find any good ones online, nor any good generators to make them. I can find good 360 images like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jg21.jpg). My question is: How can I use an image like the above to make a skybox in SceneKit? I am pretty sure it's possible because Apple has it on their website:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmaterialproperty/1395372-contents

(You have to scroll down a bit to see it)

So is there a way to do this, and how?
Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356070/how-to-set-contents-of-scenekit-background-to-cube-map