# SceneKit - Xcode 9: removing the box's line border

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am new to SceneKit, currently playing around with it.

I use 4 boxes as walls to create a sort of skybox.
[image: box]

Each box/wall has its own starfield texture. Currently this causes the borders of the walls to be visible. I want to remove these line borders, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

That is a result of the texture you use, which is not seamless. Look into "seamless tileable" textures. A much better approach to do what you are trying to do however, is to use the scene’s background property as explained in the answer of this question: [How to set contents of scenekit background to cube map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356070/how-to-set-contents-of-scenekit-background-to-cube-map)